# Toggle Showing List Of Items (Div) When Clicking On Parent Div - jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to toggle a list of months when a user clicks on a div with a "select month" input within a form:

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/q4971so8/10/)

```js
function initMonthDropDown () {
  $(document)
    .on('click', '.birth-month-input', function () {
      $(this).closest('.birth-month-dropdown').toggleClass('.opened');
    })
}
```

```css
.login-form-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
}

.input-field {
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 33px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 0;
    width: 131%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.input-field-bottom {
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 7px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 0;
    width: 142%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.select-month-input-field {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    color: #666666;
}

.form-icon {
    width: 20px;
}

.email-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 7px;
}

.key-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 7px;
}

#login-button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1584C6;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#login-button:hover {
    background-color: #0e5b8b;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.or-section-container-div {
    display: flex;
}

.or {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#left-line-only {
    padding-left: 23px;
}

#right-line-only {
    padding-right: 23px;
}

.left-line, .right-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #1584C6;
}

.hr-line {
    border: 0;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    width: 96%;               
    background-color:#000000;
    height: 1px;
}

.birth-month-arrow {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: -104px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.birth-month-input {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.birth-month-dropdown{
    display: none;
}

.birth-month-dropdown.opened {
  display: block;
}

.birth-month-dropdown-opened {
  display: block;
}

#login-button {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 34%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ui.html">
                <div class="login-form-div">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="input-field-bottom" required>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-div">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="input-field-bottom" required>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-div birth-month-input">
                    <input readonly type="text" placeholder="Birth Month" class="input-field-bottom select-month-input-field" 
                    required onclick="initMonthDropdown(event)">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lYuRGlN.png" class="birth-month-arrow"/>
                    <div class="birth-month-dropdown"> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            January
                        </div>  
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            February
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            March
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            April
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            May
                        </div>  
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            June
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            July
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            August
                        </div>
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            September
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            October
                        </div>
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            November
                        </div> 
                        <div class="birth-month">
                            December
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-div">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Birth Day" class="input-field-bottom" required>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-div">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Session Code" class="input-field-bottom" required>
                </div>
                <button onClick="login(event)" id="login-button">Log In</button>
            </form>
```

As you can see, the first issue is that, according to the editor here on SO, `initMonthDropDown` is not defined.  How's it not defined, though? Sorry, I'm new to jQuery - but I thought it was defined here:

```
function initMonthDropDown (event) {
}
```

Then, it doesn't seem to be doing anything, and maybe I have a misunderstanding of what `toggleClass` does - I thought that `toggleClass` would add `opened` to the closest element with a `birth-month-dropdown` class.

So, shouldn't that activate one of these styles?

```
.birth-month-dropdown.opened {
  display: block;
}

.birth-month-dropdown-opened {
  display: block;
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/q4971so8/10/)

Then, I'll want the selected month to show up in the input field, but that's the next step. First I'm just trying to get a better understanding of how `toggleClass` works, so that I can show or hide the list of months when a user clicks on the `birth-month-input` div.

So this is what I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: Your child selector on the delegate event handler is missing the `.` to denote it as a class.  Looks like a typo

Comment: Hmm I've added `.`'s but still no result: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/q4971so8/14/

Comment: Also the element you are trying to find with `closest()` is not a parent of the other element.  `closest()` only matches against the same element, and all parent elements.  It does not match against siblings or anything else.